# cant import data from different excel files using macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on an excel vba code to import data from different excel files into one.

There are 3 files named `supplier-a`, `supplier-b` and `supplier-c`; whose data I want to import in `zmaster.xlsm`. All these 4 files are in a folder named `untitled folder` in my desktop.

I wrote the following code but it says that code will not work with a break and it highlights the `dir=("...")` line when debugged. The path mentioned is totally correct and I have tried this code on both mac excel and excel 2007(windows). Can someone please help me with this?

My code:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim erow
    **MyFile = Dir("\Users\Ananyashree\Desktop\untitled\ folder")**
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        If MyFile = "zmaster.xlsm" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        Range("A2:D2").Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        ActiveSheet.Paste Destination = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1),     Cells(erow, 4))
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it correct to use `untitled\ folder` in your Dir() path, or should it just be `\...\untitled folder` ?

Comment: @ssice I answered to your comment in my answer below. It does not matter if the path is correct or not. The command should work. Only on Mac it will not work as wildcards are not supported on Mac.

Comment: Disregarding your error for now - `MyFile` would contain only the *name* of the file, not the full path, so unless the current directory is set to `folder` your `Open` call will fail.  You will need to pass the full path to `Open`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AddIn from the link below.  It will do all you want and more.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should read the online help for the `Dir` function on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278779%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Then it would become clear that your system does **not** support the use of wildcards such as `?` or `*`. It states on that site that you should use the following command instead on a Mac (as a wildcard replacement search):

```
Dir("SomePath", MacID("TEXT"))
```

<sub>Tip: You can easily lookup any function on MSDN by highlighting the word in the VBE and then pressing `F1` for help. At least this works on Windows. But there is probably / surely something equivalent on the Mac.</sub>

@ssice It doesn't matter if the path is correct or not. The `Dir` function is just there to verify a certain path. You could even use `MyFile = Dir("Z:\\/x   fh-_")` and the code should still work without a problem (and so it does on my system). Yet, `Dir` will return in such a case a `vbNullString` which indicates that the path / file could not be found. But again, the line should work without an error.

But you are certainly right to recommend to the OP some additional lines of code to verify **if** a file / path was found and the path verifies. Normally, I include additional lines like these:

```
If MyFile = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "File / path could not be found." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
    Exit Sub
End If
```